# Complete log management (python)

Tags: python, linux, monitoring, logging

Similar questions have been asked, but I have not come across an easy-to-do-it way

We have some application logs of various kinds which fill up the space and we face other unwanted issues. How do I write a monitoring script(zipping files of particular size, moving them, watching them, etc..) for this maintenance? I am looking for a simple solution(as in what to use?), if possible in python or maybe just a shell script.

Thanks.

Comment: what are the unwanted issues?do u want to delete the contents in the log file when it reached specific size..

Comment: As in, yeah have some logic around various kinds of log files, their size, zipping some, removing some, etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "standard" way of doing this (atleast on most Gnu/Linux distros) is to use [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html). I see a `/etc/logrotate.conf` on my Debian machine which has details on which files to rotate and at what frequency. It's triggered by a daily cron entry. This is what I'd recommend.

If you want your application itself to do this (which is a pain really since it's not it's job), you could consider writing a custom [log handler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#module-logging.handlers). A RotatingFileHandler (or TimedRotatingFileHandler) might work but you can write a custom one.

Most systems are by default set up to automatically rotate log files which are emitted by syslog. You might want to consider using the SysLogHandler and logging to syslog (from all your apps regardless of language) so that the system infrastructure automatically takes care of things for you.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to do this from my application itself.

Comment: I'd recommend logrotate rather than a homebrewn solution. If your (python) app is long running, you can use a WatchedFileHandler to make sure that it doesn't die when the file has been rotate as sorin mentions in his answer.

Comment: Why the -1? It's annoying when people randomly downvote without any reasons. I'd like to know if something is wrong in the answer or if it can be improved in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) to do the work for you.

Remember that there are few cases where it **may not work properly**, for example if the logging application keeps the log file always open and is not able to resume it if the file is removed and recreated.

Over the years I encountered few applications like that, but even for them you could configure logrotate to restart them when it rotates the logs.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. The Python logging module handles logging. Not log rotation (although it can do some of that using special handlers). Syslog is just one way of doing this but it's not really cross platform.

Comment: It would be polite to give some kind of attribution if you're simply going to copy the pith of my answer wholesale.

Comment: Yeah, stealing answers is lame.

Comment: First this was not a copy (not even inspired), and second it contains important details missing from your answer. You should spend more time answering other question instead of flaming.

Comment: I'm not flaming. You initially suggested that the python logging module would solve all his problems. After I posted my answer that mentioned logrotate and syslog and my comment on yours, you changed yours completely to mention the same things. That looked like stealing answers to me. As for the extra details you mentioned, I gave you credit for them in my second comment to under my own answer.